Accessing order item when using the woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta hook?
Is there a way to access the order item when using the woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta hook? Is there a global $item or something similar to declare?
I'm trying to set certain meta fields to be hidden conditionally based on another meta field and/or some properties of the product itself. I assume this hook is called for each order item, so I think doing this here would be appropriate, but maybe there is a better way to do this?
I would have expected to find this solution by googling or in another post here somewhere, but I haven't found it. Apologies if I missed it. Thank you.

Could you please provide, in your question, your real code attempt using woocommerce_hidden_order_itemmeta hook and global $item; even if $item is not really defined and your code doesn't work?

It doesn't matter what the conditions are, just add your hidden meta fields to the array since it only uses this hook to check if the fields should be hidden when viewing the order.
